# iOS 5 + iPad 1 = Less Memory Available

Tags: ipad, memory, crash, memory-management, ios5

I have a problem with an existing application for iPad. It is quite sophisticated application written partly native (downloading, local caching and so on), partly using Sencha Touch for UI (without PhoneGap).

Application runs fine on both iPad 1 and iPad 2 under iOS4. But with public release of iOS 5 aproblem appears for iPad 1 users. Application crashes after several seconds of work. Some guys [write](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3400742?start=15&tstart=0) that instead of 78 there are only 30 megs of memory available for iPad 1 under iOS 5. And the other blackbox is the UIWebView. Nobody knows its internal limitations.

I have a few ideas how to optimize JavaScript and HTML aspect. For example I've optimized structure and reduce memory allocations in scripts as I could. I've also replaced IMG tags with DIV + background-image. But crashes remains.

Below is the insane solution to the problem.

**Solution**

There are memory warnings but I can release neither something native nor anything inside JavaScript, I thought. So I decided to do ridiculous thing - to allocate the dummy array of several megabytes and release it on memory warning. This is nuts but it works for me: I could allocate up to 100 megs of RAM on start with simple malloc()

```
// Member variable
void* dummy;

// - (void)init    
dummy = malloc(100000000L);
```

and free it with free() when system asks.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if (dummy) {
        free(dummy);
        dummy = nil;
    }
}
```

This time app works longer. So far so good... Next step - make possible repeated memory freeing.

```
// Member variable
NSMutableArray* _memoryWorkaround;

// - (void)init
int chunkCount = 100;
int chunkSize = 1L * 1024L * 1024L; // 1 megabyte

_memoryWorkaround = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:chunkCount];

for (int i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++)
    [_memoryWorkaround addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:malloc(chunkSize)]];
```

Here it is - 100 chunks of memory by 1 megabyte allocated. This parameters is subject to revise.

Now we can free up as much memory as needed:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if ([_memoryWorkaround count]) {
        NSValue* val = [_memoryWorkaround objectAtIndex:0];
        free([val pointerValue]);
        [_memoryWorkaround removeObject:val];
    }
}
```

On exit free remaining:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    if ([_memoryWorkaround count]) {
        for (NSValue* val in _memoryWorkaround)
            free([val pointerValue]);
        [_memoryWorkaround removeAllObjects];
    }
    [_memoryWorkaround release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The last thing to do - is to fill buffer back to chunkCount with NSTimer one by one block.

Seems crazy I know. Is better solution exists?

Comment: I like the way you have framed your title. ;)

Comment: This seems totally crazy, but I am curious.  Where are you allocating this memory?

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not completely solve the problem. My program still crashes. After the reboot of device it works quite long but when many programs are already run in background may receive memory warning followed by crush. It seems that the main problem is deeper in UIWebView implementation.

Comment: Have you looked at this with Instruments? I have a similar problem, and I haven't seen a cause with instruments. But if you haven't tried it, I'd be interested in what you find out and how you set it up.